# How to upload themes in wordpress bigger than 2mb with Xampp as localhost

Tags: windows, wordpress, xampp, themes

I currently building a website with wordpress, but i can't upload a theme which size bigger than 2mb, i already change the php.ini upload-max-filesize to 100mb but it still didn't work, can anyone help me?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: hi Maximillian, when i tried it still didn't work, it won't upload the file :(

Answer (score 0):

After change upload-max-filesize  you have to once restart XAMPP  again. :)